# GROUP BY with CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

How do I define a `GROUP BY` query for my CursorLoader?

The two constructors for a `CursorLoader` I see take either a single `Context` or a `Context`, `Uri`, `projection`, `selection`, `selectionArgs` and `sortOrder`.

But no `groupBy`.

(I'm using the support package for a Android 2.3 device)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not really...

You can define a specific URI to your specific GROUP BY clause.

For example, if you have a table mPersonTable, possibly grouped by gender, you can define the following URIs:

```
PERSON
PERSON/#
PERSON/GENDER
```

When querying, switch between your queries so you can add your group by parameter:

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
   String groupBy = null;
   switch (mUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
      case PERSON_ID:
         ...
         break;
      case PERSON_GENDER:
         groupBy = GENDER_COLUMN;
      case PERSON:
        SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        builder.setTables(mPersonTable);
        builder.setProjectionMap(mProjectionMap);
        return builder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, sortOrder, limit);
      default:
         break;
   }
}
```

In fact, you could pass any sort of parameters to your query

Obs.: Use a UriMatcher to match the uri with your query implementation.

Comment: This is actually a great work-around, eventhough it requires the content provider to support it! Thanks!

Comment: @JPMagalhaes: Please help me. I am doing same thing but not getting how to get that implement. Can you please put some more code on how to change it.

Comment: or where to use this function

Comment: What is exactly your question? The key point is to find a way of setting the groupBy clause in your content provider, what is not directly possible using LoaderManagers. So you need to define a specific URI for this.

Answer (score 7):

You can add Group by with **selection** parameter

```
new CursorLoader(context,URI,
                        projection,
                                selection+") GROUP BY (coloum_name",
                        null,null);
```

Comment: I'm marking this as useful because it seems to be the only answer that works with existing content providers (you can't add a uri for the group)  But it is a bit frightening that it works.

Comment: This did not work for me. The generated sql query has mismatched number of parenthesis and no matter what I tried to make them match by adding or removing parenthesis, I always got a mismatch and thus a syntax error.

Comment: Can you try with exact syntax provided, `selection+") GROUP BY (coloum_name",` dont use closing paranthesis in selection

Comment: This will not work If the context URI has predefined condition specified such as call logs default condition ((type != 4)) AND ((phone_account_hidden = 0)). It will only work if the URI doesn't have any predefined condition.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently (and this is a bit embarrassing) the very first line in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) clearly states that the `CursorLoader` queries the `ContentResolver` to retrieve the `Cursor`. While the `ContentResolver` doesn't expose any means to `GROUP BY` there is, hence, no way the `CursorLoader` could expose such functionality either.

So the apparent answer to my very own question is: ***You can't!***